# Disable controls in GMap.js

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to update the map system on my site, to use a more current plugin for Google Maps v3. The plugin I decided to go with, was:

https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html

I've got it working, but I can't for the life of me work out how to disable the controls:

[image]

Basically, all the bits I've marked in red, I don't want to show. Here is how I'm actually calling the map:

```
modal_map = new GMaps({
    div: '#popup_map',
    lat: coords[0],
    lng: coords[1]
});
```

Can anyone suggest how I would go about removing the controls? As you can see, I'm on a pretty tight space - so I don't want any of it being wasted on those bits :)

Comment: Why on earth has someone down voted my question? Its a totally reasonable thing to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) documented control options into the GMap constructor:

```
disableDefaultUI: true
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var coords = [37.4419, -122.1419];

function initialize() {

  var modal_map = new GMaps({
    div: '#popup_map',
    lat: coords[0],
    lng: coords[1],
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  modal_map.map.set("disableDefaultUI", true);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#popup_map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<div id="popup_map"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, you beauty! Thank you, that did it :)